# SQL insert/union all returns data only from last table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this query, data exists for both category A and B in the #tmpSources table. The issue is when attempting to insert the data from #tmpSources and then query it from the #tmpFinalSource table, the query results only include the data from the second insert. Removing the second temp table and only trying to do a UNION ALL on the select statements instead also returns results where category is B. Why would the second insert delete the data from the first into #tmpFinalSource? Why would the UNION ALL only return the last table?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    CREATE TABLE #tmpSources (Category VARCHAR(30), a INT, b INT, c INT, d INT, e INT, f INT, code INT, xtype VARCHAR(100), num INT);
    -------------------Source------------------------
    INSERT INTO #tmpSources
    SELECT 'category', a, b, c, d, e, f, code, xtype, SUM(num) as num
    FROM #tempRawSource t
    JOIN dbo.TAB_SourceTable vbls ON vbls.ID = t.code
    GROUP BY a, b, c, d, e, f, t.code, vbls.xtype;


    CREATE TABLE #tmpFinalSource (Category VARCHAR(50), Cat VARCHAR(50), a int, b int, c int, d int, e int, f int, code varchar(50), xtype varchar(100), num int, Total int)
    
    INSERT INTO #tmpFinalSource
    SELECT 'A_Category', 'All' AS Cat, a, b, c, d, e, f, code, xtype, SUM(num) as num, t1.Total
    FROM #tmpSources a 
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT SUM(num) as Total FROM #tmpSources a WHERE [All] = 1  AND Category = 'A' 
    ) t1 
    WHERE [All] = 1 AND Category = 'A' 
    GROUP BY Category, code, xtype, a, b, c, d, e, f, t1.Total;

    INSERT INTO #tmpFinalSource
    SELECT 'B_Category', 'All' AS Cat, a, b, c, d, e, f, code, xtype, SUM(num) as num, t1.Total
    FROM #tmpSources a 
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT SUM(num) as Total FROM #tmpSources a WHERE [All] = 1  AND Category = 'B' 
    ) t1 
    WHERE [All] = 1 AND Category = 'B' 
    GROUP BY Category, code, xtype, a, b, c, d, e, f, t1.Total;

   SELECT * FROM #tmpFinalSource

   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Data Result Format

'B', 'All', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 234, 'Baste', 2, 2

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Based on the code presented it shouldn't return any rows at all. `#tmpSources` is initially populated with rows where `Category` is the varchar literal `'category'`. The subsequent inserts into `#tmpFinalSource` are only looking for `#tmpSource` rows `WHERE Category = 'A'` and  `WHERE Category = 'B'` which won't match anything because they're all `'category'`.

Comment: I should have made it clear that category is just a place holder word, not the actual text in the tmpSources table.